# How to keep Android awake in background when screen is off

Tags: android

I runs web server in my rooted Android  Tablet. I setup it for web development. I created a home network by this Android server. but when the screen of the tab turns off, the server also stop working & again start working when i turn on the screen. but its not possible to turn on the screen for long time. I can be harmful for my tablet. Is there any way to keep awake my tablet when the screen is turn off so that my server can work properly in Background.
please help

Answer (score 1):

You can run a service in the background and acquire lock like this :

```
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();
```

and return onStartCommand `START_STICKY`. To release the wake lock, call `wakelock.release()`.
Do not forget to put the permission in the manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Or you can use this app to prevent phone from sleeping :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine

Comment: bro can you please describe it?

Comment: where should i put this code       PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakelockTag");
    wakeLock.acquire();

Comment: You can create an app that have a service running in the background to prevent the the phone from sleeping.

Comment: You can try this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.syntaxa.caffeine

Comment: Thanks a lot bro :) can i get your facebook id please

Comment: Yes sure. facebook.com/kady.muhammad